# How can I choose which string to use after split?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How can I choose which string to use after split?

Like If I have "1,The sky Is Blue,T", and I split the string with split(","c), how can I choose if I want to print just "The Sky Is Blue"?

Comment: set a breakpoint. hold your mouse over the split array and you'll see.  or simple trial and error - you have a 1 in 3 chance of getting it right on your first try

Comment: Count the values in the split `array` (length = n), generate a random number between 1 and n (where n is the length of the array and reference `array[n]` for the value.

Comment: Yes you can choose, but will it always be the second or...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking but it seems kind of obvious... Since you are splitting comma, it will be the second element in the array.

```
    Dim s As String = "1,The sky Is Blue,T"
    Dim v() As String

    v = s.Split(",")

    Console.WriteLine(v(0))
    Console.WriteLine(v(1)) ' <-- Here
    Console.WriteLine(v(2))
```